# Steps for Removing a Site from Windows 2003 Active Directory

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

What are the steps to delete a site from AD 2003 that no longer exists. A MS knowledge base gave instructions for removing it out of Sites and Services but it still exists in AD under mydomain>>_msdcs>>dc>>sites. Is it a manual delete from both locations, any others?, or is there a process to clean it up everywhere?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the adsiedit tool - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773354(WS.10).aspx

This will help you clean up the objects that are lingering in AD...

Good luck!